# MySQL table design, one row or more pr user?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

Using MySQL I have table of users, a table of matches (Updated with the *actual* result) and a table called users_picks (at first it's always going to be 10 football matches pr. gameweek pr. league because there's only one league as of now, but more leagues will come along eventually, and some of them only have 8 matches pr. gameweek).

In the users_picks table should i store each 'pick' (by pick I mean both 'hometeam score' and 'awayteam score') in a different row, or have all 10 picks in one single row? Both with a FK for user and gameweek. All picks in one row would mean I had columns with appended numbers like this:

`Option 1: [pick_id, user_id, league_id, gameweek_id, match1_hometeam_score, match1_awayteam_score, match2_hometeam_score, match2_awayteam_score ... etc]`

and that option doesn't quite fill me with joy, and looks a bit stupid. Especially since there's going to be lots of potential NULLs in the db. The second option would mean eventually millions of rows. But would look like this:

`Option 2: [pick_id, user_id, league_id, gameweek_id, match_id, hometeam_score, awayteam_score]`

What's the best practice? And would it be a PITA to do all sorts of statistics using the second option? eg. Calculating how many matches a user has hit correctly in a specific round, how many alltime correct hits etc.

If I'm not making much sense, I'll try to elaborate anything. I just wan't my table design to be good from the start, so I won't have a huge headache in a couple of months.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second choice is much better than the first. This is called [database normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and makes querying easier, not harder. I would suggest reading the linked article, and the related descriptions of the various "normal forms", and aiming for a 3rd Normal Form data structure as a minimum.

To see the flaw in your first option, imagine if there were to be included later a new league with 11 matches. Or 400.

Answer (score 1):

You should read up about [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

When you have a 1:n relation, like in your case one team having many matches, you would create two tables. One table "teams" and a second table "matches" where each row includes the ID of the team which played the match.

In the same manner you should also have separate tables for users, picks and leagues.

Answer (score 1):

Option two is better, provided you INDEX your table properly, since (as you indicate) it will grow quite large. The `pick_id` is the primary key, but also create an INDEX on the `user_id` field, as likely the most common query will be

```
SELECT * FROM `users_pics` WHERE `user_id`=?;
```

to get all the picks for a given user.